# Error while installing keras_ocr through pip on macbook M1 Chip

Tags: python, numpy, keras, ocr, apple-m1

I am using macbook with M1 Chip and trying to install keras_ocr using `pip install keras-ocr` (PS:I have tried for the solutions available over the community for fixing the dependent numpy, scikit-image and scipy libraries but with no luck. Hoping for a better result here) but the process gives me the following error:

> writing manifest file 'numpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
> Copying numpy.egg-info to build/bdist.macosx-11-arm64/wheel/numpy-1.20.0-py3.9.egg-info
> running install_scripts
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/tmp477g6zd0_in_process.py", line 363, in 
> main()
> File "/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/tmp477g6zd0_in_process.py", line 345, in main
> json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
> File "/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/tmp477g6zd0_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
> return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
> File "/private/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/pip-build-env-0xvtwy70/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 211, in build_wheel
> return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
> File "/private/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/pip-build-env-0xvtwy70/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 197, in _build_with_temp_dir
> self.run_setup()
> File "/private/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/pip-build-env-0xvtwy70/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 248, in run_setup
> super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
> File "/private/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/pip-build-env-0xvtwy70/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
> exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'), locals())
> File "setup.py", line 513, in 
> setup_package()
> File "setup.py", line 505, in setup_package
> setup(**metadata)
> File "/private/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/pip-install-pt17o4qn/numpy_75c19d1baee74ce88c2532a40c962c58/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
> return old_setup(**new_attr)
> File "/private/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/pip-build-env-0xvtwy70/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line 165, in setup
> return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
> File "/private/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/pip-build-env-0xvtwy70/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
> dist.run_commands()
> File "/private/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/pip-build-env-0xvtwy70/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
> self.run_command(cmd)
> File "/private/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/pip-build-env-0xvtwy70/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/private/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/pip-build-env-0xvtwy70/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 328, in run
> impl_tag, abi_tag, plat_tag = self.get_tag()
> File "/private/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/pip-build-env-0xvtwy70/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 252, in get_tag
> plat_name = get_platform(self.bdist_dir)
> File "/private/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/pip-build-env-0xvtwy70/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 48, in get_platform
> result = calculate_macosx_platform_tag(archive_root, result)
> File "/private/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/pip-build-env-0xvtwy70/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/macosx_libfile.py", line 356, in calculate_macosx_platform_tag
> assert len(base_version) == 2
> AssertionError

```
        ########### EXT COMPILER OPTIMIZATION ###########
        Platform      :
          Architecture: aarch64
          Compiler    : clang
  
        CPU baseline  :
          Requested   : 'min'
          Enabled     : NEON NEON_FP16 NEON_VFPV4 ASIMD
          Flags       : none
          Extra checks: none
  
        CPU dispatch  :
          Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'
          Enabled     : ASIMDHP ASIMDDP
          Generated   :
                      :
          ASIMDHP     : NEON NEON_FP16 NEON_VFPV4 ASIMD
          Flags       : -march=armv8.2-a+fp16
          Extra checks: none
          Detect      : ASIMD ASIMDHP
                      : numpy/core/src/umath/_umath_tests.dispatch.c
        CCompilerOpt._cache_write[796] : write cache to path -> /private/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/pip-install-pt17o4qn/numpy_75c19d1baee74ce88c2532a40c962c58/build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/ccompiler_opt_cache_ext.py
  
        ########### CLIB COMPILER OPTIMIZATION ###########
        Platform      :
          Architecture: aarch64
          Compiler    : clang
  
        CPU baseline  :
          Requested   : 'min'
          Enabled     : NEON NEON_FP16 NEON_VFPV4 ASIMD
          Flags       : none
          Extra checks: none
  
        CPU dispatch  :
          Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'
          Enabled     : ASIMDHP ASIMDDP
          Generated   : none
        CCompilerOpt._cache_write[796] : write cache to path -> /private/var/folders/xl/bj72r_d95rd13lh4blhmjbm5pdf4wb/T/pip-install-pt17o4qn/numpy_75c19d1baee74ce88c2532a40c962c58/build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.9/ccompiler_opt_cache_clib.py
        [end of output]
  
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
  Failed to build numpy
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
  [end of output]
```

> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
> × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
> │ exit code: 1
> ╰─> See above for output.
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Comment: These messages do not say anything, please note the "See above for output.".

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, **numpy** build dependencies is breaking and the problem comes only with macbook not with linux systems

Comment: I don't see why Linux is relevant to be mentioned here. Also try to format errors correctly in the editor.

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/2027